# How can I import a bunch of meta tags into HTML?

Tags: php, html, import

I have some meta tags which are identical in the all pages of my website. Also I have three layout (which have its own `<head>` tag).

I guess copy/pasting those meta tags into those three layout is not standard. So  I want to make a file named `meta_tags.txt` and import it in the `<head>` of all layouts. Is doing that a good idea? if yes, is it good to use php function `requre()`? like:

```
// layout1.php

<html>
    <head>
        <?php require(__DIR__."../meta_tags.txt"); ?>
```

Comment: this seems fine. just remember `require()` throws fatal error if path doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just make it PHP file not TXT and use include not require to avoid errors,

```
<?php include('meta.php'); ?>
```

done!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a `txt` file for meta tags and not a `php` file:
You should put meta content with `PHP tags` in a php variable in the txt file. And then access those PHP variables in your main file.

You can do this in two approaches:

1st Approach:

Keep your "meta.txt" like this,

```
<?php 
    $meta_content = array( 
        "abc",
        "pqr",
        "xyz"
    );
?>
```

and then, "index.php"

```
<?php 
    include('meta.txt');
    foreach($meta_content as $meta){
        echo $meta // printing $meta_content array values.
    }
?>
```

2nd approach:

in your meta.txt file:

```
<?php
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
echo '<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">';
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">';
echo '<meta name="author" content="John Doe">';
echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">';
```

And then include this file in your `index.php`

```
<?php 
    include('meta.txt');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Require and include are used to load PHP resources (files), for your case you could use [**file_get_contents()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."../meta_tags.txt"); ?>
```